# How to store huge converted string form Base64 to string in android

Tags: android, base64

I am working on a android project where i am converting the image into BASE 64 format and i am able to get the string, but i am unable to store this huge String what i am getting  in a string.

I need to pass the resulting string as a parameter to API. but i am getting only half image like below

[image]

Because i  am getting half image the data is not getting stored properly in the database

Comment: How exactly are you trying to store the string?

Comment: Please edit your post to include the code snippet.

Comment: and then what are you doing with the string? why you think that you are unable to store it?

Comment: `as a parameter to API.` ???? What are you doing?

Comment: `and i am able to get the string` ? It does not look like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you copied the string from the Logcat then you got only the first part of the string as logging to logcat logs only the first part of long strings.

Better save the base64 string to file. Open in a text editor and then copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

It might help you -

```
 public void onImageCompress(Bitmap image) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);
    byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
    String ba1= Base64.encodeToString(ba, Base64.DEFAULT);
    generateNoteOnSD("imagebytes.txt", ba1 + "");

}
public void generateNoteOnSD(String sFileName, String sBody) {
    try {
        File root = new File(getExternalFilesDir(sFileName), "image");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append(sBody);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        System.out.println("Saved");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Call onImageCompress method and pass your bitmap. This will generate a file with a string. Now use this link (as you used in your question) [convert base64 to image](http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) to see the image. 
First of all try to test with small sized images then go for big one.